# Mapping few streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I have few Maps with the same key `name` and different value types.

```
Map<String, Long> map1 = ...
Map<String, Long> map2 = ...
Map<String, String> map3 = ...
```

What I want to achieve is to, out of this three different maps, compose a new Map:

```
Map<String, Foo> fooMap = ...
```

Where Foo is a class:

```
class Foo {
  long val1;
  long val2;
  String val3;
}
```

Is it possible to do it with Streams API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `Stream` over the entries of one of the maps, and map each entry to an entry of the output `Map`:

```
Map<String,Foo>
   outMap = map1.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(e -> new SimpleEntry<>(e.getKey(),
                                            new Foo(e.getValue(),
                                                    map2.get(e.getKey()),
                                                    map3.get(e.getKey()))))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,Map.Entry::getValue));
```

This is assuming your `Foo` class has a 3 argument constructor.

EDIT: As Anton commented, you can skip the `map` step:

```
Map<String,Foo>
   outMap = map1.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                          e -> new Foo(e.getValue(),
                                                       map2.get(e.getKey()),
                                                       map3.get(e.getKey()))));
```

Comment: Why are you using this intermediate temporary  `SimpleEntry`? Why not just create Foo in collector? `.collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,e -> new Foo(e.getValue(),
                                                    map2.get(e.getKey()),
                                                    map3.get(e.getKey())) ))`

Comment: @AntonBalaniuc I just didn't think about it. Your approach certainly works.